# how can i sort out multiple subcollection document that also contains in my main collection... firebase v9

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWNTy.jpg)[ÍÍ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUD8P.jpg)

data structure like this ...

main col | docs | sub col | sub docs

users | list of users docs{

KobMpUh0fJTm7UwXynOfwbOkefi1,
UzKxbD6LiBPJgCwqdV8fJ9EAKaz2,
sOJXLLJNvAVis8HxP4Df3G8thiu2,
xLAL3AvnhmMyQPWMonFUUCRSht92

} | list of sub col {swipes} for each user | list of sub docs {

KobMpUh0fJTm7UwXynOfwbOkefi1
UzKxbD6LiBPJgCwqdV8fJ9EAKaz2
}

How can i find the user col id that exists in sub-col{swipes} .

thanks

Comment: Please format your question: include the image in the question and not as a link and format the code snippets.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your question, you should use a [Collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).

Comment: thank you ... but is there a way to list out all sub collections that contain  different collections

Comment: Can you clarify your comment? What do you exactly mean by "sub collections that contain different collections"? Can you add some examples in your answer?